# py2exe will not install

Tags: python, py2exe

I am trying to download py2exe but every time that  run the setup program it says "no python installation found in registry" but I have downloaded python 3.4 and have it on my computer working? please help.

I'm using a 64 bit computer with the 64 bit py2exe, I downloaded python from the python website.  And i'm on windows 8

Comment: Maybe the python path variable is not set which results in python not being found by other programs.

Comment: You should give more information on your setup, for instance which OS version you are using,  how/where from you installed python

Comment: Make sure that you didn't download the 64-bit version of py2exe if you have 32-bit Python and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [cx_Freeze](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cx_Freeze) instead py2exe.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have installed everything properly. In your install settings you can choose if you want to assign the **system variable** python.as you can see from the [point 3.3 of the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/using/windows.html#configuring-python), you should:

> 3.3.1. Excursus: Setting environment variables¶
>
> Windows has a built-in dialog for changing environment variables (following guide applies to XP classical view): Right-click the icon for your machine (usually located on your Desktop and called “My Computer”) and chooseProperties there. Then, open the Advanced tab and click the Environment Variables button.
>
> In short, your path is:

```
My Computer / Properties / Advanced / Environment Variables
```

> In this dialog, you can add or modify User and System variables. To change System variables, you need non-restricted access to your machine (i.e. Administrator rights).
>
> Another way of adding variables to your environment is using the set command:

```
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;C:My_python_lib
```